# Cannot connect Win10 to WPA2-Enterprise WiFi Network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I am trying to connect Windows 10 to a wifi network with WPA2 Enterprise (PEAP/MSCHAP) network hosted by a Unifi AC-LR Access Point. I can connect with Android with my username and password. But Windows refuses to connect. It just says something about checking security requirements, and then that it "cannot connect to this network." Now it won't even ask me for credentials anymore, even though I told it to forget the network. I completely reset all network settings (Network Settings Reset in the Settings). I tried manually adding the network via Settings. I don't know what else to try. Chrome OS and Android can connect but Windows just refuses.